# Scope of Trigger in a button not complete - Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am using below mentioned Style to change the style of my button. Everything is as expected however the scope of my "IsMouseOver" is only till the written content inside the button, not after that. So if I hover over written content , it gets triggered only then and NOT if I hover anywhere in the whole button. Why so ?

```
    <Style x:Key="fancyButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Navy"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="2">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"></ContentPresenter>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="border" Value="#d9e2f1"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `Background` of a `Border` (or `Grid`) to `Transparent` instead of default null

```
<Border x:Name="border" Background="Transparent" ...>
```

Comment: Alright. That did it ! I tried increasing the border width but that didn't work. Thankyou